# How to replace a string in DataFrame column (ex : [12-12-12] io [12/12/12])

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace "/" to "-" in the column `df['tran_date']`:

[image: DataFrame here]

I have tried this but it does not work :

```
df['tran_date'].replace('/','-')
```

Could you please help? Thank you!

David

Answer (score 3):

`replace` replaces the whole cell value, to replace a part of the string you need to use `str.replace`:

```
df['tran_date'] = df['tran_date'].str.replace('/','-')
```

Comment: @jezrael So you're doing lots of pandas/python in your job or this is just a hobby to pass time? ;)

Comment: I am hobby coder.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this .

```
df['tran_date'] = df['tran_date'].str.replace('/','-')
```

Comment: How is it different from my answer?

Comment: We both answered at the same time bro ..

Comment: What If I questioned you same :D?

Comment: Weird coincidence since the post was 3 hours old

Comment: Yup it just showed me in my feed and I answered and after posting I found out that you've also answered it..

Comment: Probably it went up when I answered it ;)

Comment: I dont know bro but when I opened it, there was no answer.. I think you posted answer while I was writing..

Comment: You posted it first, So I am giving you a vote up :)